# custom extension for php in .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to use a custom extension for php say for example '.newext'

To do this I have added the following code to .htaccess

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .newext
```

But when i run a file with this extension, the php code is not executed and instead the file is getting downloaded with the php code

this is my file 'file.newext'

```
<?php echo "welcome"; ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to explain how Apache and PHP are configured. While this is the default MIME type for PHP scripts, it could as well be configured as FCGI action handler.

Comment: I am using a shared hosting and i added this in my cpanel

Comment: if i dont specify 'Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .newext' the file is running as normal text file